# azure search index html content

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I know blob storage is the only data source (thus far) that supports the indexing of html content.

My question is, is it possible to strip content using a custom analyser and the charfilter 'html_strip' (mentioned in azure docs) before adding a document to an index via REST?

Here is my create index payload:

```
    {
      "name": "htmlindex",  
      "fields": [
      {"name": "id", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "searchable": false},
      {"name": "title", "type": "Edm.String", "filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": true},
      {"name": "html", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "analyzer": "htmlAnalyzer"}
      ],
      "analyzers": [
      {
        "name": "htmlAnalyzer",
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
        "charFilters": [ "html_strip" ],
        "tokenizer": "standard_v2"
      }
      ]
    }
```

Here is my add document to index payload:

```
    {
      "value": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "title": "title1",
          "html": [
            "<p>test1</p>",
            "<p>test2</p>"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Now when I search the index, I see the html content is not being stripped :

```
    {
      "@odata.context": "https://deviqfy.search.windows.net/indexes('htmlindex')/$metadata#docs",
      "value": [
          {
              "@search.score": 1,
              "id": "1",
              "title": "title1",
              "html": [
                  "<p>test1</p>",
                  "<p>test2</p>"
              ]
          }
      ]
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I accomplish the stripping of html from the content before I add it? Without a pre-step..

Answer (score 1):

So the custom analyzers (and the associated character filters) are optional steps that you can perform prior to tokenizing text. These analyzers help us facilitate better full-text search.

Azure search doesn't have a mechanism for modifying the contents of the document to be indexed when using the REST API to push documents to your index. You will have to do that yourself, as the analyzers are used to extract terms from documents that are stored in the search index.

More details here if you are interested: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture

Comment: Adding a data source to be indexed of a blob storage container with html files is able to separate the content from the markup.  How is this achieved? If it is not possible.

Comment: When you try to index data from blobs, we are able to run certain content extraction tools to strip out HTML, or read text from office files, PDFs and so on. This is a "pre-processing" step in a non-destructive sense as your actual blobs are not modified. When you use the REST API to push data to the index, we don't modify the actual document as there isn't a notion of "original" document.

Having said that, could you please elaborate why using Blob storage is not an appropriate choice for you? Perhaps if I understand your scenario better I could try to find alternatives if possible?